# ravendb index replication with nservicebus

Tags: replication, ravendb, nservicebus

In an attempt to make the index replication more robust in RavenDB's latest stable build, I was looking to introduce NServiceBus into a custom index replciation bundle, such that inside `ReplicateToSqlIndexUpdateBatcher` dispose when it dequeues the commands and opens a connection to sql to execute, I did rather put them on a bus and process later in a failure tolerant way. I have put the relevant config entries on `raven.server.exe.config`, given a `IStartableBus` to the ctor of `ReplicateToSqlIndexUpdateBatcher`, inside the dispose method of `ReplicateToSqlIndexUpdateBatcher` I get `IBus` from the `IStartableBus`, dequeue the command, map it to a message and `Bus.Send` it, but some how I keep getting no message destination specified as an error in raven studio. I have added the message mappings to the config, and also tried adding it programmatically using the fluent interface when obtaining a `IStartableBus`, but to no avail. 
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to do so.
We have a new SQL Replication bundle that will handle this scenario robustly.

Comment: Where is the bundle? Can I use it with the latest stable version? Last I checked the latest stable version 2230 has the same code as 960.

Comment: It's in the new 2261 just out today.  It's not documented yet, but it's shown in this video: http://youtu.be/KlpawSkHD4U